# Webpage: accessing xml file without extension

Tags: xml, url, html, host

Here is my problem.
An "application" uses an xml page to get some informations.

```
[...] url=https://secure.motogp.com//en/video/demand/meta/206769&[...]
```

If you visit that url an xml document will be displayed, without .xml being in the url. Fine.

I need to edit it, so I downloaded and edited the xml file.

The problem is that this "application" access the xml file without an extension.

```
/206769 and not /206769.xml
```

I tried to upload the EditedFile.xml somewhere and replacing the link, but it doesn't work. If I try to access it by typing mywebsite.com/EditedFile it finds nothing (obviously).

I need to be able to upload the edited file, on my website or anywhere else,and be able to access it without ".xml" at the end.

Any idea?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Did I understand it correctly? 1. It works when you access `/EditedFile.xml`. 2. You want to upload it as `EditedFile.xml` (not as `EditedFile`). 3. You want to make it available under `/EditedFile`. --- Which server do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My server is nginx.
Basically, I need to tweak an external script. This script load some informations from a certain page, that returns an xml file. The problem is that the link to this page does not contain .xml extension.

In order to change the parameters, I need a custom .xml page, but without the .xml extension, because the original link to the original info-page does not contain the xml extension, only numbers.